# Grunt remove async and defer from my scripts and css

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm working on a webapp with AngularJs and I'm using Grunt for compile and tasks. When I compile with *serve:dist*, Grunt doesn't add async/defer to main.css and scripts.js files. I have others scripts with async/defer outside of grunt tags and this scripts keeps async/defer.

Index.html:

```
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
  <link async rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <link async rel="stylesheet" href="styles/global.css">
  <link async rel="stylesheet" href="styles/map.css">
  <link async rel="stylesheet" href="styles/core_app.css" data-main-css="1">
  <link async rel="stylesheet" href="styles/fonticons_app.css" media="screen">
  <link async rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/landing_app.css" media="screen" />
<!-- endbuild -->

  <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
  <script defer src="scripts/settings.js"></script>
  <script defer src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <script defer src="scripts/services/localize.js"></script>
  <script defer src="scripts/services/mobiledetection.js"></script>
  <script defer src="scripts/services/storage.js"></script>
  <script defer src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
  <script defer src="scripts/controllers/general.js"></script>
  <script defer src="scripts/services/api.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I researched and I think the problem is in the tasks usemin or filerev of Gruntfile but I didn't find a solution:

```
// Renames files for browser caching purposes
        filerev: {
            dist: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
                ]
            }
        },

// Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                flow: {
                    html: {
                        steps: {
                            js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                            css: ['cssmin']
                        },
                        post: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,**/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
            }
        },
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, the issue is that the processed tags have async/defer removed from them? If so, have you looked at the `blockReplacements` function of the `usemin` task? https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#blockreplacements

It looks like you can provide a function that lets you define how to replace the script and link tags for your assets. For example, it looks like you could add the following to options for the `usemin` task to accomplish what you want:

```
blockReplacements: {
  css: function(block) {
    return '<link async rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + block.dest + ' />';
  },
  js: function(block) {
    return '<script defer src="' + block.dest + '"></script>';
  }
}
```